# Send scroll event to form

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar, richtextbox

In my windows forms application it occurs frequently that a user scrolls through a panel and is then blocked by a `richtextbox`. I would like to catch the scroll event and send it to the panel when the `richtextbox` vertical scrollbar is not visible.

I already found the code to check if the vertical scrollbar is visible in this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3facad3-0eae-4610-9a63-1b6c7a718bf5/how-do-you-determine-if-vertical-scroll-bar-is-visible-in-richtextbox?forum=winforms

Also the `VScroll` event of a `richtextbox` is only triggered when the verticalscrollbar is already visible.

What would be the correct way to catch the mousescroll and send it to the correct panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can add a event  to your rich text box in your Form1.Designer.cs like this code:

```
this.richTextBox1.MouseWheel += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.richTextBox1_MouseWheel);
```

and add this function to your form:

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    if (!NativeMethods.VerticalScrollBarVisible(control))
    {
        int numberOfTextLinesToMove = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;
        int numberOfPixelsToMove = numberOfTextLinesToMove * Convert.ToInt32(control.Font.Size);
        if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value - numberOfPixelsToMove < panel1.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        else if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value - numberOfPixelsToMove > panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        else
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value -= numberOfPixelsToMove;
    }
}
```

The `VerticalScrollBarVisible` method is explaned in [this MSDN thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3facad3-0eae-4610-9a63-1b6c7a718bf5/how-do-you-determine-if-vertical-scroll-bar-is-visible-in-richtextbox?forum=winforms).

Comment: Thank you, this MouseWheel event also triggers when the scrollbar is not visible. I have suggested a edit to add the code that sends the scroll value to a panel.

Answer (score 0):

The event `MouseWheel` suggested by @Farshad does also trigger when the vertical scrollbar is not visible. I then added the following code to scroll `panel1`. Note that the `MouseWheel` event is not show in the visual studio designer and must be added to Form.Designer.cs manually.

```
private void richTextBox1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Control control = sender as Control;
    if (!VerticalScrollBarVisible(control))
    {
        int numberOfTextLinesToMove = e.Delta * SystemInformation.MouseWheelScrollLines;
        int numberOfPixelsToMove = numberOfTextLinesToMove * Convert.ToInt32(control.Font.Size);
        if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value - numberOfPixelsToMove < panel1.VerticalScroll.Minimum)
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Minimum;
        else if (panel1.VerticalScroll.Value - numberOfPixelsToMove > panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value = panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum;
        else
            panel1.VerticalScroll.Value -= numberOfPixelsToMove;
    }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
private extern static int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int index);

public static bool VerticalScrollBarVisible(Control ctl) {
  int style = GetWindowLong(ctl.Handle, -16);
  return (style & 0x200000) != 0;
}
```