# Identify web browser's vertical scroll is reached on last position in c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, webbrowser-control

I have load HTML content in WebBrowser control of Winforms. And I want to append another HTML content **when vertical scroll is reached on last position**. So I am stuck on it how can I achieve it.

Here is my sample code:

```
WebBrowser web = new WebBrowser();
web.Document.Write("Some html content");
web.Document.Window.AttachEventHandler("onscroll", OnScrollEventHandler); // Create scroll event for browser control

private void OnScrollEventHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Identify vertical scroll reached on last position and append another HTML
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you can get scroll position then you can match it with `web.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height`. If both match then you reached at the bottom. Not tried but it should work.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41478520/detect-scroll-to-bottom-in-webbrowser-control

Comment: @KeyurRamoliya I have tried this but it's not working.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203749/send-scroll-event-to-form

Answer (score 2):

This will work

```
 class KeyHandle
 {
    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, 
   System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

 public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
  {
      PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYDOWN, key, 0);
   }
 }
```

Call method:

```
     KeyHandle.SendKey(this.webBrowser.Handle, Keys.PageDown);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this approach: Make two-way communication between your Winforms app (C#) and browser-side javascript, then you'll be able to call C# code from javascript, like this: window.external.GetAdditionalContent() when the scrollbar reaches the bottom.

**GetAdditionalContent** = your COM-visible method.

**How to: Implement Two-Way Communication Between DHTML Code and Client Application Code:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a0746166.aspx

**Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom:**
[Check if a user has scrolled to the bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3898130/check-if-a-user-has-scrolled-to-the-bottom)